# MySQL Classic ASP ODBC Function sequence error

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, odbc

I am using ODBC onto a MySQL database using classic ASP.

This is a pretty stable live installation used constantly. Every few days it randomly produces:

**[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error**

If the page is refreshed it goes away.

I upgraded to the latest version of the ODBC driver and that didn't seem to fix it.

Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: There is a lot of questions about this that suggest it's related to date format (query in [Google `site:stackoverflow.com +"mysql"+"Function sequence error"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%2B%22mysql%22%2B%22Function+sequence+error%22)). However, as a starting point, would recommend turning on ODBC trace logs to help you identify the underlying cause.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Couple of points... all those in your list don't seem to be related to MySQL, and seem mostly reproduceable. This one is very occasional. I haven't come across ODBC trace logs... are they something that is ok to put on a live server? Will it slow things down much or create masses of logs?

Comment: Fair point, but sometimes looking at another tech that generates the same ODBC error could help identify the cause. As for tracing, I wouldn't recommend it in a production environment for extended periods of time as it will have an impact. If you are interested in looking at ODBC Tracing you can find it in the ODBC Data Source Administrator (`odbcad32.exe`) in the Windows OS.

Comment: Other than that, as a question, there isn't a lot for us to go on other than the `Function sequence error` which seems pretty generic.